# HTML5 video not working on Safari.

Tags: html, .htaccess, video, safari, mp4

Could someone help me, html5 videos are working in Firefox, Chrome, IE but not in Safari.

I already tried changing the .htaccess. I already downloaded quicktime but I still can't play the video on Safari. These are the video file formats I use: .mp4, .webm and .ogv.

Here is a sample link: http://kontras.ca/cs_portfolio/pitem.php?pi=70&cat=6

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Works fine in Safari 6 and 5.1.17 on OS X. Takes pretty long to load though.

Comment: Do you have this issue on a PC? What happens if you access the video directly through its URL?

Comment: hi @insertusernamehere, i am accessing it using Windows 7 and Safari 5.1.17. I am not sure what is wrong.

Comment: if i access the video directly using safari, it plays the video using my VLC media player.

Comment: I already tested it using a Mac and the video works although, it takes time before the video loads. If someone finds a solution, please let me know. Thanks @insertusernamehere for checking it out.

Comment: It works on my computer: Windows 7 Safari 5.1.2

Comment: Thanks for testing it on your machine @eivers88! It might just be happening on my machine then.